# Pagination in Yii framework doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, yii, pagination

Could you possibly help me, please, I'm implementing pagination on my news page as it shown at this [page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination).

On the very first page it is working fine. But when I click on a page link to get page 2 or page 3, I get a blank result. No data, no pager. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: may be the relation in model class is not proper

Comment: right relation is not proper

Answer (score 1):

You basically just specify a page size on your data provider / active record

```
 $model = new CArrayDataProvider( $dataRow, 
         array('pagination'=> array('pageSize'=>5) ));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but where concretely should I put this two lines of code? I've just never worked with Yii before... In  "actionIndex" function in controller?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem awhile ago i resolved by changing the method name except index because by googling i found that lots of pagination doesn't work with index method i am not sure about this just sharing my experience.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it unfortunately didn't help me, the problem still remains unsolved